# Access Configuration from a View in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

How can I access [`IConfiguration`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration) in an MVC View in ASP.NET Core 1.1?

Ex. `_Layout.cshtml`

```
<link href="@Configuration["MyConfigEntry"]/css/site.min.css>
```

Answer (score 69, accepted):

In asp.net core , you can inject `IConfiguration` implementation to your views and use that :)

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration
@inject IConfiguration Configuration
<link rel="stylesheet" href="@Configuration["MyConfigEntry"]/css/site.min.css">
```

Comment: This was what I was looking for. I wanted to pass the configurations from several sources bind together in my startup.cs class and wanted to access it in my view. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

`@inject` it [into the view](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/dependency-injection) (if that's really what you want to do).

Additional documentation: [Options provided by a view model or with direct view injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-2.2#options-provided-by-a-view-model-or-with-direct-view-injection)

Comment: oyyy spent way to long trying to hack something together when i could have just used @inject... glad i now know this!

Answer (score 3):

If the posted link is where you took your example, then Probably by doing

```
<link href="@Startup.Configuration["MyConfigEntry"]/css/site.min.css>
```

This is because you set the *Configuration* object as static while bootstrap the application.

From [Configure an ASP.NET Core App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration?tabs=basicconfiguration)

```
public static IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; set; }
```

Comment: good way. but why this property is not `static` by default code in latest versions of asp.net core? are there any disadvantages for it?